# How to make a "Quit" button click event to close a program using PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working for the first time with the Pygame library and I'm having some trouble in making a simple button, whose click event will close my program. I've segmented my code in the follow way:

App.py, which contains my mainloop:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from widgets import *

class App():

    # creates object
    def __init__(self):

        self._running = True
        self._display_surf = None
        self.size = self.weight, self.height = 1000, 500

        self.button_1 = rect_Button(((255,255,255)),(500,250),"Quit")

    # initializes all PyGame modules
    # create main display & uses hardware acceleration
    def on_init(self):

        pygame.init()
        self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self._running = True
 
    def on_event(self, event):

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self._running = False

        #if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            #self._running = False

        if self.button_1.click_State:
            # testing button
            print("closing...")

    def on_loop(self):
        pass

    def on_render(self):
        rect_button_1 = pygame.draw.rect(self._display_surf,self.button_1.color,self.button_1.container())
        self._display_surf.blit(self.button_1.display_Text,rect_button_1)
        pygame.display.update()

    def on_cleanup(self):

        pygame.quit()

    def on_click(self):

        pass
 
    def on_execute(self):

        if self.on_init() == False:
            self._running = False
 
        while( self._running ):

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.on_event(event)

            self.on_loop()
            self.on_render()

        self.on_cleanup()
```

widgets.py, where i'll create classes for widgets which aren't built-in on Pygame:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

class rect_Button():

    def __init__(self, color, pos, text):

        self.font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',32)
        self.display_Text = self.font.render(text,True,((200,0,0)),None)
        self.mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        self.width = self.font.size(text)[0]
        self.height = self.font.size(text)[1]
        self.color = color
        self.pos_X = pos[0]
        self.pos_Y = pos[1]

    def container(self):
        return pygame.Rect(self.pos_X,self.pos_Y,self.width,self.height)

    def click_State(self):
        if self.pos_X+self.width > mouse[0] > self.pos_X and self.pos_Y+self.height > mouse[1] > self.pos_Y:
            if self.click[0]==True:
                return True
        else:
            return False
```

And finally game.py, where I create the App object:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from app import *

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    theApp = App()
    theApp.on_execute()
```

My problem is that I want to click on the Quit button I've created and close my program. To test it, I made it print "closing..." whenever I clicked within the button. However, it continuously prints whenever I move my mouse inside the program window. How should I tell my code to get from the button object the information that the button was clicked, run the event and close the window?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Its really hard to follow your code but I would advise creating a separate function which deals with checking for events. When you want to check for a press of a button its easier to use the following under your check `pygame.event.get()` loop:

```
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    button_clicked = easy_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y)

    if button_hard_clicked and self._running: # checks of active program/click
       # Whatever you want to do if the button is clicked
       self._running = False
```

Check out my Star Wars pygame shooting program, which also implements a button. Hope this will sort of help. The code for the button will be found in `game_functions.py` and `main.py` files.
[Here is the link](https://github.com/feifyKike/Star-Wars-Shootout.git)

Comment: Indeed, I still haven't commented my code and I apologize for its current confusing state! Meanwhile, I updated the text where I explain how I solved the problem in the meantime. Also, thank you very much for sharing your program and for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As of now,

```
if self.button_1.click_State:
```

will **not** call click_State()
To fix this, add () to the end of click_State to call the function.
Additionally, when the line is written as above, the rest of the statement will automatically carry on. (hence all of the "closing...")

```
if self.button_1.click_State():
```

The above line is closer, but the program is not checking to see if it matches anything. To fix this, change to:

```
if self.button_1.click_State() == True:
```

From there you can insert the rest of the code to close the program.
Hope I could be of help!

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing for your answer! I updated the text where I explain how I solved the problem in the meantime.

Comment: `if <condition>` is fine by itself, and explicit comparisons to `True` and `False` are in fact normally a bad idea. In English, we do not say "if it is true that it is raining" although we could; we say "if it is raining".